# Errors in building the pjsip in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, open-source, pjsip

I want to run pjsip on my iPhone simulator but I am not able to run that. I properly follow the the steps given with it. But it shows errors e.g.

[image: errors shown after build]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the static library provided is built with device architecture. Try to run the application in Device. Otherwise, get the source code and compile it for i386 architecture (to support simulator)

**Update:**
For more details, please visit this [link](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#BuildingPJSIP)

Comment: i am compiling for i386 architecture in simulator and then this errors are shown....In device also same errors are shown...i dont understand which library is not linked up properly...so help me if u can...

Comment: What I meant is, the third party libraries are built with armv6/armv7 architectures. So you cannot use them to run in simulator which requires the library in i386 architecture.

Comment: I followed all the steps given in that link.....i easily configure it and make it...after that when i run that program in code it shows all that errors....i have given the "header search path" properly and select my base sdk to latest 4.3 but then also it doesnot work....or tell me what information i can give to you so that u can tell me my mistake......